# How to hash a string with a secret key and MD5 algorithm in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, md5, bouncycastle

I am working on an API which requires a header for API authentication. The header contains a hash string which is created using md5 algorithm and a secret key. I want to write a function like this:

```
public string CreateMD5Hash(string input, string secretKey)
{
    return output;
}
```

I tried to use bouncy castle API. But I couldn't find proper documentation. That is why I couldn't make it use.

Comment: Encryption primitives work in terms of bytes, not strings. Using MD5 is quite dated so *do you know* what encoding you're meant to use to convert those strings? If not, you're not ready to write this bit of code, and we'll not know either.

Comment: Can this document help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5?view=net-5.0

Comment: Can't you simply append the two and hash that? Something like `return BitConverter.ToString(MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + secretKey)));`? (although it's probably not advised to use MD5 in 2021)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay **BASICALLY** let's break this into two simple concepts `Cryptography` and `Hashing`.

#### Cryptography

There are three fields `secrete key` a `value` and an `encrypted value`, and two methods.

- `Encrypt(value, secret-key)` this method gets `value` and `secret key` and returns the `encrypted value`.
- `Decrypt(encrypted-value, secret-key)` and this method gets `encrypted value` and `secret key` and returns the `value`.
  like `AES`, `DES`, etc ...

#### Hashing

There are just **two** fields `value` and `hashed value`, and one method.

- `Hash(value)` this method gets the `value` and returns the `hashed value`.

like `MD5`, `SHA` family, etc ...

Simple right!

So your question is not correct because `MD5` is a hashing algorithm that usually is used for hashing passwords and comparing the hash of them.

Now I recommend taking a look at the API you are talking about for authentication.

> **<sub><sup>You can share the link of documentation or an already encrypted header (if it is not sensitive data) to help you.</sup></sub>**

## Update

According to the link, it is using `HMAC` with `MD5`.
This is the sample in the document, written in `PHP`.

```
 $hash = hash_hmac('md5', $string, $key);
```

You can use this code for C#:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

...

public string HashHmacMD5(string message, string secret)
{
    Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    using (HMACMD5 hmac = new HMACMD5(encoding.GetBytes(secret)))
    {
        var msg = encoding.GetBytes(message);
        var hash = hmac.ComputeHash(msg);
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the link of the rest api documentation. Have a look into  Authentication -> Hash. If you find any solve please do let me know. Thank You. Link: https://verifone.cloud/docs/2checkout/API-Integration/REST-6.0-Reference

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat confusing.

For simple API authentication, you want to generate a secret that you want to share with the caller. This secret should be validated on your side.

Normally you would generate a random secure string with length about 50 - this is the secret. You share this secret with the caller - normally you warn the caller to securely store the value, since there is no way to recover it. **Do not store** this secret in the database.

You would generate a salt and hash the secret. You store both the salt and the hashed secret in the database. When the request comes in, you extract the value in the header, hash it with the salt and compare the result with the hashed secret in the database. User would be authenticated if they are match.

Is this more inline with your thinking? Is your question, how to hash it properly?